# Create pandas DataFrame out of list of dictionaries with nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, nested

I retrieve data from an API in JSON format and want to create a pandas data frame out of it. The content that I want to analyze is a list of dictionaries where the dictionaries do not necessarily have the same keys and some of them include nested dictionaries, too.

Now I have already achieved a result that comes very close to what I want, but I get a warning I would like to overcome (there is actually several of them using the original data):

```
...\pandas\indexes\api.py:37: RuntimeWarning: unorderable types: int() < str(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects union = _union_indexes(indexes)
```

I am using Python 3.4.2 on Windows 10 and this MWE should illustrate my issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

content = [{"Id": "A1", "SomeInfo": 0, "description": "Lorem Ipsum, lorem ipsum."},
       {"Id": "B2", "SomeInfo": 2, "otherInfo": 0, "nestedInfo": {"inf1": 3, "inf2": 3}},
       {"Id": "C3", "SomeInfo": 2, "nestedInfo": {"inf1": 3, "inf3": 2}}]

content = pd.DataFrame(content)

df = pd.concat([content.drop(['nestedInfo'], axis=1), content['nestedInfo'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

The result that I want should preferably look like this:

```
   Id  SomeInfo                description  otherInfo   inf1  inf2  inf3
0  A1         0  Lorem Ipsum, lorem ipsum.        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  B2         2                        NaN        0     3     3     NaN
2  C3         2                        NaN        NaN   3     NaN   2
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the above or ideas for better solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not getting any warnings on Ubuntu machine with python 2.7. And the output of your code looks almost exactly as expected.